# How to do a complex indexing query on a dataframe in a functional style

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I like using `query` rather than `loc` since it is can be used with operator chaining, and can sometimes save characters by not repeating the `DataFrame` name.

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe_with_a_long_name = pd.DataFrame({'animals': ['cat', 'dog']})
dataframe_with_a_long_name.query("animals == 'cat'")
```

Is there a way to do a similar thing if I want to do is not supported by `query` like `str.contains`?

```
dataframe_with_a_long_name[dataframe_with_a_long_name.animals.str.contains('c')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `0.18.1` `.loc[]`, .`iloc`, `.ix` and also `[]` [accept a callable](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/indexing.html#selection-by-callable) so you can:

```
dataframe_with_a_long_name.loc[lambda df: df.animals.str.contains('c')]

  animals
0     cat
```

Comment: very nice ... by the way the `loc` is redundant, you can just use `[]`

Comment: That's right, added all indexing varieties for completeness.